# Android OpenGL Live Wallpaper creating two renderers

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I have a working live wallpaper with a parallax effect. I've based the code off of [the openGL Tutorials](http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/).

Its been working for the most part except for when the wallpaper is previewed while it is already set as the wallpaper. After I do this my onOffsetsChanged() method keeps getting called, but the value of my camera offset in my renderer class doesn't change. This means that my parallax wallpaper becomes static. The parallax effect works again as soon as I set a different wallpaper and then switch back to this wallpaper.

Update: So, it looks like the renderer being drawn and the renderer receiving the calls for onOffsetsChanged are two separate renderers. Does anyone know why the new one is being controlled by the WallpaperService while the old one is being drawn or how to fix this?

GLWallpaperService:

```
public abstract class GLWallpaperService extends WallpaperService{
public class GLEngine extends Engine{
    class WallpaperGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
        private static final String TAG = "WallpaperGLSurfaceView";

        WallpaperGLSurfaceView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getHolder()
        {
            return getSurfaceHolder();
        }

        public void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
    }

  private WallpaperGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
  private boolean rendererHasBeenSet;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
  {
      super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

      glSurfaceView = new WallpaperGLSurfaceView(GLWallpaperService.this);

      Log.d("onCreate", "was called");
  }

  @Override
  public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)
  {
      super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
      if(rendererHasBeenSet)
      {
          if (visible)
          {
              glSurfaceView.onResume();
              //glSurfaceView.requestRender();
              Log.d("onResume", "was called");
          } else
          {
              glSurfaceView.onPause();
              Log.d("onPause", "was called");
          }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
      super.onDestroy();
      glSurfaceView.onDestroy();
      Log.d("onDestroy", "was called");
  }

  protected void setRenderer(GLSurfaceView.Renderer renderer)
  {
      glSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
      rendererHasBeenSet = true;
      Log.d("setRenderer", "was called");
  }

  protected void setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(boolean preserve)
  {
      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
      {
          glSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(preserve);
      }
  }

  protected void setEGLContextClientVersion(int version)
  {
      glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(version);
  }
    }
  }
```

OpenGLES2WallpaperService:

```
    public class OpenGLES2WallpaperService extends GLWallpaperService
{

    //set up our main_preferences
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    GLRenderer renderer;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener;

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine()
    {
        Log.d("GLES2 onCreateEngine", "engine was created");
        return new OpenGLES2Engine();
    }

    class OpenGLES2Engine extends GLWallpaperService.GLEngine
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
        {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
            Log.d("GLES2 onCreate", "surface was created");

            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpenGLES2WallpaperService.this);

            final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
            final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

            if (supportsEs2)
            {
                setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

                setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);

                renderer = new GLRenderer(OpenGLES2WallpaperService.this);

                setRenderer(renderer);

                //set up preference listener

                final SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpenGLES2WallpaperService.this);
                prefListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences mprefs, String key) {
                        if(mPrefs.getBoolean("activate_sunset", true))
                        {
                            renderer.changeColor(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            renderer.changeColor(0);
                        }

                    }
                };
                mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
                                     float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels)
        {
            renderer.setEyeX(xOffset);
//            Log.d("onOffsetsChanged", "was called");
        }

        //set up gesture detection
        private android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gestureListener = new android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
//                if(preferences.getBoolean("pref_key_sim_scroll", true))
//                    renderer.setEyeX( e1.getX() - e2.getX());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(OpenGLES2WallpaperService.this, gestureListener);

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
        {
            super.onSurfaceChanged( holder,  format,  width,  height);
            Log.d("GLES2 onSurfaceChanged", "the surface was changed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceRedrawNeeded(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            super.onSurfaceRedrawNeeded(holder);
            Log.d("GLES2 RedrawNeeded", "the surface was redrawn");

        }

    }

    GLSurfaceView.Renderer getNewRenderer()
    {
        return renderer = new GLRenderer(OpenGLES2WallpaperService.this);
    }
}
```

Renderer class (kind of messy right now):

```
public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    // Our matrices
    private final float[] mtrxProjection = new float[16];
    private final float[] mtrxView = new float[16];
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // Geometric variables
    public static float vertices[];
    public static short indices[];
    public static float uvs[];
    public FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    public ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    public FloatBuffer uvBuffer;

    // Our screenresolution
    float   mScreenWidth = 1280;
    float   mScreenHeight = 768;

    // Misc
    Context mContext;
    long mLastTime;
    int mProgram;

    //set up our main_preferences
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    //set up array database
    ArrayHolder arrayHolder = new ArrayHolder();

//  Square square, square1;
    Sprite background, mountains, forest, person;
    float offsetDifference = 1;
//  Background background;

    public void setEyeX(float offset)
    {
            eyeX = -offset * offsetDifference;
            lookX = eyeX;
//      Log.d("setEyeX", "eyeX: " + eyeX);
    }

    public GLRenderer(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        //Load in Preferences
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        // Generate Textures, if more needed, alter these numbers.
        int[] textureNames = new int[4];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(4, textureNames, 0);

        //set the scene color from preferences
        float[] sceneColor;
        if(preferences.getBoolean("activate_sunset", false))
        {
            sceneColor = arrayHolder.sunsetColor;
        }
        else
        {
            sceneColor = arrayHolder.normalColor;
        }

        //create the sprites
        person = new Sprite(arrayHolder.vertices1, sceneColor);
        forest = new Sprite(arrayHolder.vertices2, sceneColor);
        mountains = new Sprite(arrayHolder.vertices3, sceneColor);
        background = new Sprite(arrayHolder.vertices4, sceneColor);

        // Set the clear color to white
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 0);

        // Create the shaders, solid color
        int vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_SolidColor);
        int fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_SolidColor);

        riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

        // Create the shaders, images
        vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_Image);
        fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_Image);

        riGraphicTools.sp_Image = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

        // Set our shader program
        GLES20.glUseProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);

        setupImages();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        // We need to know the current width and height.
        mScreenWidth = width;
        mScreenHeight = height;
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);


        float ratio;
        if(height > width)
        {
            ratio = (float) width / height;
            Matrix.frustumM(mtrxProjection,0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
            offsetDifference = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ratio = (float) height / width;
            Matrix.frustumM(mtrxProjection,0, -1, 1, -ratio, ratio,  3, 7);
            offsetDifference = 0.5f;
        }

    }

    // Position the eye in front of the origin.
    float eyeX = 0.0f;
    float eyeY = 0.0f;
    float eyeZ = -4.0f;
    // We are looking toward the distance
    float lookX = 0.0f;
    float lookY = 0.0f;
    float lookZ = 0.0f;
    // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
    float upX = 0.0f;
    float upY = 1.0f;
    float upZ = 0.0f;

    boolean colorIsRed;

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_MVPMatrix");

//      Log.d("onDrawFrame", "eyeX: " + eyeX);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);


        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
//      Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, eyeX, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mtrxView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        background.draw(mMVPMatrix, uvBuffer, 0);

        float[] scratch2 = new float[16];
////        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, eyeX * 0.9f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch2, 0, mtrxView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch2, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, scratch2, 0);
        mountains.draw(scratch2, uvBuffer, 3);


        float[] scratch1 = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, eyeX * 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch1, 0, mtrxView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch1, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, scratch1, 0);
        forest.draw(scratch1, uvBuffer, 1);


        if(!preferences.getBoolean("pref_key_remove_layer", true))
        {
            float[] scratch = new float[16];
////        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
            Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mtrxView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, scratch, 0);
            person.draw(scratch, uvBuffer, 2);
        }
    }

    public void changeColor(int colorCode)
    {
        float[] newColor = arrayHolder.normalColor;
        switch(colorCode){
            case 0: newColor = arrayHolder.normalColor;
                break;
            case 1: newColor = arrayHolder.sunsetColor;
                break;
        }

        person.changeColor(newColor);
        forest.changeColor(newColor);
        mountains.changeColor(newColor);
        background.changeColor(newColor);
    }

    private void setupImages()
    {
        // Create our UV coordinates.
        uvs = new float[] {
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f
        };

        // The texture buffer
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        uvBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        uvBuffer.put(uvs);
        uvBuffer.position(0);

        // Generate Textures, if more needed, alter these numbers.
        int[] texturenames = new int[4];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(4, texturenames, 0);


        // Temporary create a bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.squaresky);
        // Bind texture to texturename
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[0]);
        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.squareground);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[1]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.squareperson);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[2]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.squaremountains);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[3]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

        bmp.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the GLrenderer class?

Comment: It's posted. Tell me if you need a look at anything else.

Comment: onVisibilityChanged, try to remove the requestRender call, There is no need to call that if your render always renders

Comment: Well, I commented it out, but there's no change. It's still not responding when I set the wallpaper the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like I needed to set the correct renderer to the new Surface view. I did this by moving the GLRenderer renderer to the GLWallpaperService and changing the setRenderer() to this:

```
      protected void setRenderer(GLSurfaceView.Renderer renderer)
  {
      this.renderer = (GLRenderer)renderer; //this line was missing
      glSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
      rendererHasBeenSet = true;
  }
```